# Class StandardServiceContainer not found in Propel.php

Tags: php, orm, propel

When I call the `getServiceContainer` method of `Propel` class, i get this error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Propel\Runtime\StandardServiceContainer'
>   not found in
>   /var/www/webservices/vendor/propel/propel/src/Propel/Runtime/Propel.php
>   on line 118

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, it is because when i include or require the config.php which it is called getServiceContainer method, I had to require or include autoload.php for propel.Changing the require or include order of the php files solved my problem.